# R: as.POSIXct timezone and scale_x_datetime issues in my dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, posixct

I spent some time trying to figure out why the hour ticks were shifted when scale_x_datetime was applied. I've tried to give the timezone when the Date/Time column was created. I used ggplot and scale_x_datetime() from the package scales. The hour ticks were wrong, which datapoint did not match the time in their Date/Time column.

Here is some procedures to deal with my dataset.

```
  DF$DateTime<-as.POSIXct(DF$timestamp,format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M", tz="America/Toronto")
  DF$Date<-as.Date(DF$DateTime)

  lims <- as.POSIXct(strptime(c("2015-07-21 00:00","2015-07-23 00:00"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), tz="America/Toronto")    

  ggplot(DF) + geom_line(aes(x=DateTime, y=-Diff,group=Date)) + scale_x_datetime(limits =lims, breaks=date_breaks("2 hour"), labels=date_format("%m/%d %H:%M"))
```

Do I miss anything here?? Please help me to figure it out.
Many thanks!

Comment: Related https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4007 & https://community.rstudio.com/t/problem-with-scale-x-datetime-timezone-parameter/66314

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The function `date_format()` takes a `tz` argument that is by default set to `"UTC"`. Therefore, your labels are converted to UTC. To use the time zone "America/Toronto", you can do the following:

```
scale_x_datetime(limits = lims, breaks = date_breaks("2 hour"),
    labels = date_format("%m/%d %H:%M", tz = "America/Toronto"))
```

This argument was introduced with version 0.2.5. Code that uses `date_format()` to create plots in other time zones than UTC must be changed after the update.

Comment: I need to specify the tz in the data_format. There is a type in your post. It should be like this: labels = date_format("%m/%d %H:%M", tz = "America/Toronto")

Comment: @Kuo-HsienChang You are right and I corrected the mistake. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 5):

Update for ggplot 3+. `scale_x_datetime` allows you to set the x-axis time zone directly (using a syntax slightly different than that given in older answers).  The correct code now is:

```
scale_x_datetime(limits = lims, breaks = date_breaks("2 hour"),
                 date_labels = "%m/%d %H:%M",
                 timezone = "America/Toronto")
```