# Time data in x axis not ordered in R ggplot

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I am using the following data frame in R

```
TIME                 PRICE
2013-01-01 23:55:03 446.6167
2013-01-01 23:55:02 441.0114
2013-01-01 23:54:59 446.7600
```

I am using function ggplot to plot the data points and label fixed intervals using `scale_x_datetime`.

```
library(ggplot2)  # including necessary libraries
lims <- as.POSIXct(strptime(c("2013-01-01 00:00:00","2013-01-01 23:59:00"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))


ggplot(open,aes(x=TIME,y=PRICE))  
   + geom_point(size = 1.0, color="navy") 
   + xlab("Time") 
   + ylab("Price") 
   + ggtitle("time vs Price ") 
   + scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("200 min"), minor_breaks=date_breaks("15 min"), labels=date_format("%H:%M:%S"),limits=lims)
```

Despite specifying the limits, the `x` axis labels are not in order as shown beneath:

[image]

Comment: Could you post the output of `str(open)` at the bottom of your question?

Comment: it is already posted in the very beginning

Comment: Also avoid names to objects such as `open` (since it is a function of `R`)

Comment: This looks like it could be a time zone issue.  Are you using the most current version of ggplot2?  The most current version defaults to using the time zone attached to the variable, but I remember that whatever the previous default was could lead to problems.

Comment: A likely duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227130/r-as-posixct-timezone-and-scale-x-datetime-issues-in-my-dataset)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `as.POSIXct(TIME)` in you `aes` like so. I had to change your code a bit to fit your limited 3-point data example.

```
open <- read.table(text="TIME                 PRICE
'2013-01-01 23:55:03' 446.6167
'2013-01-01 23:55:02' 441.0114
'2013-01-01 23:54:59' 446.7600",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

lims <- as.POSIXct(strptime(c("2013-01-01 00:00:00","2013-01-01 23:59:00"),
                   format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

ggplot(open,aes(x=as.POSIXct(TIME),y=PRICE)) +  
geom_point(size = 3.0, color="red")+ 
xlab("Time")+ 
ylab("Price")+ 
ggtitle("time vs Price ")+
scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("360 min"), 
                 minor_breaks=date_breaks("15 min"), 
                 labels=date_format("%H:%M:%S"),limits=lims)
```

[image]

**EDIT**
You should try to use `xts` to transform your data in a time series object. This will order the time correctly. Then, you `fortify` it to use with ggplot2.

```
library(xts)
open <- read.table(text="TIME                 PRICE
'2013-01-01 23:55:03' 446.6167
'2013-01-01 23:55:02' 441.0114
'2013-01-01 23:54:59' 446.7600",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
open <- xts(open$PRICE,as.POSIXct(open$TIME))
open <- fortify(open)

lims <- as.POSIXct(strptime(c("2013-01-01 00:00:00","2013-01-01 23:59:00"),
                            format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

ggplot(open,aes(x=Index,y=open)) +  
geom_point(size = 3.0, color="green")+ 
xlab("Time")+ 
ylab("Price")+ 
ggtitle("time vs Price ")+
scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("360 min"), 
                 minor_breaks=date_breaks("15 min"), 
                 labels=date_format("%H:%M:%S"),limits=lims)
```

[image]

Comment: @SahityaSridhar Not sure what you are saying. In my example, the x-labels are ordered from midnight to midnight.

Comment: In my example the x label ordering doesn't change at all. Could it be because of the difference in the data frame?

Comment: Even when i execute your code i dont get the labels in the right order

Comment: @SahityaSridhar I made an edit which uses `xts`, which is very effective for time series data. It will also order the data correctly.

Comment: Nope. Still the same ordering.

Comment: Do you see factors in `str(open)`? If so, you should add `, stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

Comment: There aren't any factors in str(open)

Answer (score 0):

I would use lubridate:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
time<-seq(ymd_hms('2013-01-01 00:00:01'),ymd_hms('2013-01-02 23:59:59'), by = '1 min')
price<-sample(length(time))
dt<-data.table(time,price)

ggplot(dt,aes(x=time,y=price))  + geom_point(size = 1.0, color="navy") + xlab("Time") + ylab("Price")  + ggtitle("time vs Price ")
```

resulting in:

[image]